# Are there some other ways to deduce resistance from current, than Ohm's Law (e.g. because why'd we assume a linear relationship?)?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Are there some other ways to deduce resistance from current, than Ohm's Law (e.g. because why'd we assume a linear relationship?)?

Also, are Kirchoff's laws usually often in conjunction with Ohm's Law, because aren't

$$\sum I=0, \sum V=0$$

slightly useless for practical purposes on their own (without adding Ohm's Law to the above)?

Comment: I kind of think of Ohm's Law as being the definition of resistance.  I'm not sure what you'd use as your definition of resistance, if you were hoping to somehow calculate it without using Ohm's Law.

Comment: One could measure ohmic heating by calorimetry, using $P = I^2R$.

Comment: How is Ohm's law or Kirchhoff's laws "slightly useless for practical purposes"? It is the most used laws in the first steps of electronics design.

Comment: Resistance is the inverse of conductivity.

Comment: @Steeven I wrote that **only** Kirchoff's laws (without Ohm's Law) seem to be useless on their own. For practical purposes.

Comment: @user34793 But that's already Ohm's Law. I asked whether one can deduce without it.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you are looking to find. Resistance is *defined* as the ratio of voltage-to-current. Sure, resistance appears in several expressions and formulas, but it always means "resistance against current flow". This is very fundamental and what we call Ohm's law, just like mass being a fundamental "resistance against acceleration" and therefore appearing in many formulas, although it is defined in Newton's 2nd law. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmmic.html

Comment: @Steeven I find it unintuitive that the phenomenon of electricity would be linear, if it's a measure of particles.

Answer (score 3):

Kirchhoff's laws (two *h*'s in Kirchhoff) are relationships that hold, in the *quasi-static* limit, between voltages and currents in a circuit, regardless of the nature of the elements in the circuit. Whether you have a circuit composed of resistors, capacitors and transistors, and one composed of potatoes, carrots and bananas, Kirchhoff's laws hold.

Ohm's law is a so-called *constitutive equation*, that is, a relation that specifies the behaviour of a certain circuit element; in this case, the two-terminal *linear resistor*. From the point of view of circuit theory, Ohm's law actually *defines* the linear resistor: it is that element for which the voltage across its terminals is directly proportional to the current crossing the element, and the coefficient of proportionality is called *resistance*.

Therefore, you "deduce" or, rather, you directly calculate, determine or measure the resistance by employing its very definition, as you would do for any other quantity.

Comment: So Ohm's Law equates to the definition of resistance?

Comment: @mavavilj Yes, Ohm's law gives the definition of resistance.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for resistance is pretty oddly worded. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance. It writes that the definition of resistance is $R=V/I$. Then writes that "this proportionality is called Ohm's Law" . As if the proportionality and the definition would be different things.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano You do not need Ohm’s law to define resistance.

Comment: @Farcher You can certainly define the resistance as the ratio of the voltage across any two-terminal resistor, linear – obeying Ohm's law – or not, and the current through it. However, for nonlinear resistors, such a definition is usually not particularly useful and can be also misleading; and you can also define a differential resistance or, for nonlinear circuits with reactive elements, a resistance defined in terms of dissipated power. This is why I restricted the above definition to linear resistors, as is done by most authors.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano An example of using the resistance at a particular voltage or current of a non linear component is a light bulb which needs a series resistor or inductor or capacitor to be at its working voltage when connected to a power supply whose voltage is greater than that of the working voltage of the light bulb.

Comment: @Farcher In that case you don't really need the concept of resistance to choose the series resistor. But my point is slightly different: to define the resistance as $V/I$ for a generally nonlinear resistor, that is, an element which is defined by a relationship of the type $f(V,I)=0$, you have to be careful because that relationship might not be put in functional form globally. Therefore, you have to specify under which conditions to obtain $V/I$, e.g., if driving the element with a current or a voltage.

Comment: You might want to have a look at L. Chua, _Linear and nonlinear circuits_. I don't think the OP is ready for such a discussion ;-) Of course, in practical cases with mild nonlinearities, things are much more simple.

Comment: @Farcher I discussed a case with a nonlinear resistance here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/303798/111969