# In a grid of resistors, why can one assume that $2\alpha + \beta = 1$?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

In the following formulation of part of the infinite grid problem

[image]

Why can one assume that $1$ (of current) entering a node must equal $2 \alpha + \beta$ current?

Why aren't all the three other quantities separate?

I.e. that

$$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$$

or same

$$3 \alpha = 1~?$$

Answer (score 1):

[Kirchhoff's Current Law:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law_(KCL))

> At any node (junction) in an electrical circuit, the sum of currents flowing into that node is equal to the sum of currents flowing out of that node.

I presume that the central node is one electrode, and the other is connected in a ring at infinity. Then the grid has **circular symmetry** about the central node. The 4 nearest nodes are identical if rotated, or if reflected about a diameter.

So all the currents marked $\alpha$ are identical and those marked $\beta$ are identical. But $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not the same because the $\alpha$ are perpendicular to the radius while the $\beta$ are along the radius.

Comment: Exactly that Kirchhoff's law that the OP claimed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/384179/111969) to be slightly useless ;-)

Comment: This does not answer why it's $2 \alpha + \beta$.

Comment: @mavavilj I have updated my answer.